# how to leave only one value (the most recent) from the array of duplicates in R

Tags: r, dplyr

here little example

```
mydat=structure(list(a = c(8, 83, 8.5, 8.5, 7.5, 7.8, 7.5, 8, 7.5, 
8, 8), b = c(69.5, 70, 69.5, 68.5, 70, 69.5, 69.5, 70, 69.5, 
68.5, 70), PROB_POSTR_KM = c(378884L, 378884L, 378884L, 378884L, 
378884L, 378884L, 404136L, 404136L, 404136L, 404136L, 404136L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

Here variable `PROB_POSTR_KM`. It has value `378884`  and count of this value=`6`
Value `404136` (count `5`)

how to remove duplicate values if they exist and leave only the most recent one.
In this case, the desired result looks like

```
    a    b PROB_POSTR_KM
1 7.8 69.5        378884
2 8.0 70.0        404136
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydat)

mydat[, tail(.SD, 1), PROB_POSTR_KM]
#    PROB_POSTR_KM   a    b
# 1:        378884 7.8 69.5
# 2:        404136 8.0 70.0
```

Comment: Isn't this also `mydat[!duplicated(PROB_POSTR_KM, fromLast = TRUE)]`

Comment: Yes. I was surprised to see none of the answers in the linked dupe use `duplicated`

Comment: I like `duplicated` as it is fast.  Haven't tested on big datasets with a group by vs duplicated

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)

mydat %>% 
  group_by(PROB_POSTR_KM) %>% 
  slice(which.max(1:n()))
```

Gives us:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   PROB_POSTR_KM [2]
      a     b PROB_POSTR_KM
  <dbl> <dbl>         <int>
1   7.8  69.5        378884
2   8    70          404136
```

Comment: There is a `slice_tail(n = 1)`